# unable to create table from foreign table taking long time

Tags: postgresql, query-optimization, foreign-data-wrapper

taking long time to create table with foreign tables

query

```
select distinct a."scid", a."tt", a."p"
into tableA
from db1_foreigntable1 a
join db1_foreigntable2 b on  a."scid" = b."obid"
join db1_foreigntable3 c on a."scid" = c."scid"
join db2_foreigntable1 d on c."tr" = d."tr" and d."st" = 'A'
WHERE b."vid" = 'ck98098089';
```

explain plan

```
"Unique  (cost=1118498.39..1345123636.54 rows=1630056 width=1074)"
"  ->  Nested Loop  (cost=1118498.39..236056972.07 rows=147875555263 width=1074)"
"        ->  Foreign Scan  (cost=1118397.82..1406741.03 rows=2031252 width=57)"
"              Relations: ((db1_foreigntable1 a) INNER JOIN (db1_foreigntable2 b)) INNER JOIN (db1_foreigntable3 c)"
"        ->  Foreign Scan on db2_foreigntable1 d  (cost=100.57..114.13 rows=139 width=10)"
```

explain analyze

```
"Unique  (cost=1118498.39..1345123636.54 rows=1630056 width=1074) (actual time=257.649..765380.721 rows=409229 loops=1)"
"  ->  Nested Loop  (cost=1118498.39..236056972.07 rows=147875555263 width=1074) (actual time=257.647..764798.024 rows=916789 loops=1)"
"        ->  Foreign Scan  (cost=1118397.82..1406741.03 rows=2031252 width=57) (actual time=254.342..100453.211 rows=3033849 loops=1)"
"              Relations: ((db1_foreigntable1 a) INNER JOIN (db1_foreigntable2 b)) INNER JOIN (db1_foreigntable3 c)"
"        ->  Foreign Scan on db2_foreigntable1 d  (cost=100.57..114.13 rows=139 width=10) (actual time=0.177..0.177 rows=0 loops=3033849)"
"Planning Time: 26.183 ms"
"Execution Time: 777131.106 ms"
```

how  to mitigate this query I was created FDW with postgres_fdw extension

I was set below parameters for foreign server

```
use_remote_estimate - true
 
extensions - fdw_functions

fetch_size - 50000
```

Comment: The explain plan seems to think it needs to compare 1.4 trillion rows which probably will take a while. If db1 and db2 are different databases then the join condition can't be pushed down. Does table d have a useful index at least?

Comment: db1 and db2 are different databases. and table d has indexes where the columns involved in where conditions

Comment: How big is db2_foreigntable1?  How big does it think it is?  What plan do you get if you set enable_nestloop=off?

Comment: "unable" and "taking long time" are different things.

Comment: taking long time .. If I set enable_nestloop=off also